# Flutter: FloatingActionButton has no shadows and touch animation

Tags: flutter

The default FAB in the demo app has shadows and a ripple effect when touched.

[image: Proper FAB]

However, when the FAB is moved to another class, it suddenly loses this effect, which makes it look rather plain.

[image: Lame FAB]

Is it possible to bring the shadows and ripple animations to the plain looking FAB while keeping it in a separate class?

**Main.dart**

```
import 'package:test_app/TestItem1.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new TestItem1(),
    );
  }
}
```

**TestItem1.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestItem1 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(
                'test 1',
              ),
              new Text(
                'test1',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          onPressed: null,
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The floating action button is disabled by default if you gave nothing to

`onPresss()`

if you don't want to give in onPress just pass `(){}` an anonymous method